# How do I use syntax highlighting in PHP within a markdown github gist?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, markdown, gist

I want to include code in a [markdown gist on github](https://gist.github.com/derekdreery/8933123), and cannot work out how to do syntax highlighting.

github flavoured markdown - e.g.

````
```php
    Class::function($param);
```
````

would highlight the syntax as php in an issue, for instance, but it seems not in a gist.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Fenced code blocks do work in Markdown Gists, and in fact your code *is* being rendered that way. If you inspect the blocks you'll see that they are contained in `div`s with `class="highlight highlight-PHP"`.

The problem is that PHP code is only recognized for highlighting by GFM if it includes the `<?php` delimiter (much like PHP code only runs inside a `<?php` block). Add this to the top of each PHP code block and you should be good to go, e.g.:

````
...

```php
<?php
class GO_Example_Model_Thing extends GO_Base_Db_ActiveRecord {
    ...
````

Answer (score -1):

Use this HTML comment tag before the block:

```
     
<!-- language: php -->
```

then your block of code and the rest of que answer/question:

```
     
    Class::function($param);
    // more code...
```

**Important rules:**

- Don't indent the HTML comment.
- Enter a new empty line after the comment.
- If don't work insert a new empty line before the comment and the indented code too.

You can check the [Stack Overflow's Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and a more elaborated [meta's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Comment: That works on Stack Overflow, but not GitHub. (Also, the language was already being correctly detected for the OP, as indicated by the `class="highlight highlight-PHP"` attribute.)

Comment: I didn't realize the question is focused on GitHub, I answered without read it well. Thanks @chris for your comment, wiser to point my mistake than downvote anonymously.